# Cisco gateway and firewall changing addresses?

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, arp

We have a Honeywell control board that has an Ethernet controller.  We have assigned a static IP address as such:

```
IP:  10.2.112.12
Mask:  255.255.254.0
GW:  10.2.112.2
```

The gateway is a Cisco router.  Periodically, the device will become unreachable from outside the subnet it's on.  After running a Wireshark capture, I see that, during the night, the device went from asking for ARP requests to get the MAC address of 10.2.112.2 to asking for the MAC address of 10.2.112.4 (which is our Cisco ASA firewall).

I have reached out to the vendor of the board and they insist it's an issue with our network.  I still think it's their board, but does anyone have any ideas what might be configured on our network to cause this behavior?

Thanks,

-Scott

Comment: Does the router have any route that has the asa ip as next hop?

Comment: And in the capture what do you see just before it starts arping for the asa?

Comment: Yes, the default route (0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0) is pointing to the ASA for internet access.  Just before that I see it ARPing for the gateway.  I may not be getting all packets though.  I may need to span the port.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect what happens is that the board sometimes tries to connect to something on the Internet, so it sends this to the router but the router sends an icmp redirect, instructing the board to send this traffic directly to the asa. You can use

> debug ip icmp

On the router to confirm, and/or configure

> no ip redirects

on the router's interface towards the board, to prevent this from happening.

See [When are icmp redirects sent](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/routing-information-protocol-rip/13714-43.html)